# Cannot run python program in Vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

you just know it by seeing the picture
[I don't know what to do...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me9KV.png)

I tried many things from google tried putting the same file path to launcher.json but nothing worked even tried reinstalling the whole visual studio code

As asked adding launch.json file code:
[launch.json code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1SCX.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the `launch.json` configuration that you're using so that we could see how you are trying to run the script. Also, have you simply tried executing the `python <script_path>` in the terminal?

Comment: follow the Python VSC Tutorial in the doc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the generic configuration for running a currently open file?

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `launch.json` is missing some content. We can let vscode create relevant content automatically.

1. Delect `launch.json` in your .vscode floder.
2. Click **Run and Debug** button on the left (Or use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+D").
3. Click **create a launch.json file** and choose Python.

[image]

You can read [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) for more details.